# Duplicate a line of text in notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++, editing

before

```
man
woman
friend
love
```

after

```
man man
woman woman
friend friend
love love
```

Does anyone know about doing this using a text editor or cmd?

Comment: tag this with "regex" and you might get someone who knows.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Well, you could use something like this:

Find:

```
^.*$
```

And replace by

```
$0 $0
```

Make sure you have the following settings:

[image]

Comment: awesome, exactly what I was looking for...